# GET url of endpoint

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

I'm trying to develop a sequence in Wso2 esb. I need to log the URL of the endpoint

this a snippet of my sequence

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
        var log = mc.getServiceLog();
        var requestBody = mc.getProperty("requestBody");
        log.info("Avant de checker l'adresse "+requestBody.city);
        mc.setProperty("addressNonNull",1);
        if (requestBody.street || requestBody.zip || requestBody.city || requestBody.country) {
            if(requestBody.street) {
                mc.setProperty("query.param.street",requestBody.street);
            }
            if(requestBody.city) {
                mc.setProperty("query.param.city",requestBody.city);
            }

            mc.setProperty("addressNonNull",1);
        }

        log.info("crm_create_subtasks_v2 address_value  ==>"+requestBody.street+"|" +requestBody.zip+"|"+requestBody.city);
        ]]>
    </script>   
    <switch source="get-property('addressNonNull')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <case regex="1.0">
                <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
                <property name="Content-Encoding" action="remove" scope="transport"/>
                <property name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('user:password'))" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>

                <call>
                    <endpoint key="jira_address_exist_v2"/>
                </call>
                <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="check address exist"
                    scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
                <log>
                    <property name="create_subtasks_v2 response jira_address_exist_v2" expression="json-eval($.)"/>
                </log>
```

I need to display URL generated befor making request to the endpoint "jira_address_exist_v2" in the logs.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Add this just before the call mediator,

```
 <log level="simple"/>
 <call>
    <endpoint key="jira_address_exist_v2"/>
 </call>
```

Comment: Thanks Ravindra. I added that but it doesn't display anything in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but at least you can give it a try. Add the following just before .

```
<log level="full">
<property name="To" expression="$trp:To" />
<property name="TO" expression="$trp:TO" />
</log>
```

If this doesn't work you can also enable wire log. Go to the esb console -> confiugre -> logging and search for a class xxx.http.wire and enable debug. Then you'll see what the esb receives and sends out.